# html submit via python

Tags: python, html, python-requests

what is the html submit forum that is needed to submit posted data on fb,

script source code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.facebook.com/login/identify/"
target_profile = raw_input("Enter the Target's Profile Link: ")
payload = {"email": target_profile, "submit": "submit"}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)

f=open('results.html', 'w')
f.write(r.content)
f.close()
```

html source:

```
<label class="uiButton uiButtonConfirm uiButtonNoText" id="did_submit" for="u_0_5"><input value="Search" name="did_submit" id="u_0_5" type="submit"></label>
```

is the payload correct?
not sure why it isnt sending the payload, after the it saves the response in html file and open it via firefox i dont get the response as i was hoping, the html file should contain the page of where to send reset code with there email and phone number blanked out except the last 2, but its just showing the page where it says enter the profile url to look up for a pass reset with the target_profile variable in the searchb ar....

Comment: You need to find the url where the `/login/identify` does the POST request

Comment: wouldnt it be after the submit with a action="https://facebook.coim/login/" something like that?? new to scraping been trying for days to get this to submit and at least save to make sure the html has the right content

Comment: having a hard time understanding what ur saying, one not very good with html still learnig but 2 this is the whole block for the submit and cancle section of the page, after submitting the profile url

Comment: "<div class="rfloat _ohf"><label class="uiButton uiButtonConfirm uiButtonNoText" id="did_submit" for="u_0_2"><input value="Search" name="did_submit" id="u_0_2" type="submit"></label><a role="button" class="uiButton" href="/login.php"><span class="uiButtonText">Cancel</span></a></div>"

Comment: Add any aditional content as part of your question, not as a comment

Comment: The action of the form is `/ajax/login/help/identify.php?ctx=recover`, and the name of the field is `email`.